# Python: swarm plot covers the median line in box plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, swarmplot

When plotting a swarm plot (seaborn) over a box plot, the points may cover the median line of a box plot.
How can I do the swarm plots dots a bit more transparent so that I also see the median of a box plot?

On the plot we do not see the median line because it is covered by the dot, so, optically I do not know where the median is on the second box. Is it possible to do the points of the swarm plot more transparent so that I also see the median line?

Example:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1,figsize=(6,2))
data = pd.DataFrame({'a':[3,3,3,3,4,5,6,8,11,11,8,7,7,7,7,7,7,3,3,3,3,3,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,9,10,11,12,11,11,11]})
sns.boxplot(x='a',data=data, ax = axes)
ax = sns.swarmplot(x='a', data=data, color = 'grey', ax = axes)
```

(Making a larger figure is not an option)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options come directly to my mind:

- **Make the swarmplot translucent**. This can be done by adding the `alpha` argument, e.g. `alpha=0.5` for half-transparent. Of course the darker the bar in the background, the less visible the points are (hence I made it yellow here).

  ```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import seaborn as sns
  import pandas as pd

  fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,2))
  data = pd.DataFrame({'a':[3,3,3,3,4,5,6,8,11,11,8,7,7,7,7,7,7,3,3,
                            3,3,3,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,9,10,11,12,11,11,11]})

  sns.boxplot(x='a',data=data, ax = axes, color="gold")
  sns.swarmplot(x='a', data=data, color = 'grey', ax = axes, alpha=0.5)

  plt.show()
  ```

  [image]
- **Show the median line on top of the swarmplot points**. This can be done by specifying the `zorder` of the medianline via a dictionary passed through the `medianprops` keyword argument.

  ```
  sns.boxplot(x='a',data=data, ax = axes, color="gold", medianprops={"zorder":3})
  ```

  [image]
  In this case, making the median line half-transparent via `medianprops={"zorder":3, "alpha":0.6}` is equally possible.

Of course any combination of the two options can help as well.